# How to get existing template (or) look and feel old farm to new farm in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, development

I am new SharePoint. We are using SharePoint 2013 environment for our project, under that so many sub-sites are created. Now we setup new farm 2013 for Development purpose. In our current farm(Production), when we create new subsite, we will get title image as our company logo and front coming in blue colour etc. They same way we need for our Development farm. Means we need company logo, front colour etc when create sub-site.  How to achieve it.

Can we extract any existing template (or) code (or) .wsp file (or) development files from our current farm(Production farm) to Development farm for achieving above request? could anyone please suggest (or) share steps if possible.

Note: Mount and un-mount database was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a backup of the production DBs and moving them to the Dev SQL server and attaching them to the DEV SharePoint environment is the best option.